# Maven compile mixed Java + Groovy 1.7 project, using gmaven-plugin

Tags: java, groovy, maven, compilation, gmaven-plugin

As per the top two answers in: [maven dependencies groovy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1876286). I'm trying to compile a mixed Java 6 + Groovy project with Maven, using the GMaven-plugin from org.codehaus.gmaven. Up until yesterday we were using the old `1.6.0` version of Groovy (never changed it after we finally got it working), but since `1.7.0` is now stable I thought we'd switch to that.

If only things were that simple.. The problems I'm now encountering seem to be two fold:

- `Groovy 1.6` is somehow still picked up as the default. (as show in the stacktrace below)
- groovy:generateStubs stops with a build error: Unexpected node: Node[7:1,64,ANNOTATIONS]

Does anyone know how to solve the above two problems, or can provide a working pom to compile `Java 6` code intermixed with `Groovy 1.7` code with Maven?

There's a lot of confusing / contradicting / outdated documentation on compiling old versions of Groovy using gmaven / groovy.maven / groovy.maven.gmaven that's really not helping things right now..

For reference, here's part of my pom.xml & the Maven -e output:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
        <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.gmaven</groupId>
            <artifactId>gmaven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.gmaven.runtime</groupId>
                    <artifactId>gmaven-runtime-1.7</artifactId>
                    <version>1.2</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
                    <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
                    <version>1.7.0</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>generateStubs</goal>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                        <goal>generateTestStubs</goal>
                        <goal>testCompile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Stacktrace:

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Client
[INFO]    task-segment: [clean, package]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [clean:clean {execution: default-clean}]
[INFO] [groovy:generateStubs {execution: default}]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] BUILD ERROR
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Unexpected node: Node[7:1,64,ANNOTATIONS]

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Trace
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Unexpected node: Node[7:1,64,ANNOTATIONS]
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoals(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:719)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoalWithLifecycle(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:556)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoal(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:535)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoalAndHandleFailures(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:387)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeTaskSegments(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:348)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.execute(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:180)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:328)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:138)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:362)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.compat.CompatibleMain.main(CompatibleMain.java:60)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
        at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:315)
        at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:255)
        at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:430)
        at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:375)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Unexpected node: Node[7:1,64,ANNOTATIONS]
        at org.codehaus.gmaven.plugin.MojoSupport.execute(MojoSupport.java:85)
        at org.codehaus.gmaven.plugin.stubgen.AbstractGenerateStubsMojo.execute(AbstractGenerateStubsMojo.java:60)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultPluginManager.java:490)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoals(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:694)
        ... 17 more
Caused by: org.codehaus.gmaven.runtime.support.stubgen.UnexpectedNodeException: Unexpected node: Node[7:1,64,ANNOTATIONS]
        at org.codehaus.gmaven.runtime.support.stubgen.parser.NodeSupport.ensure(NodeSupport.java:96)
        at org.codehaus.gmaven.runtime.support.stubgen.model.ModelFactorySupport.identifier(ModelFactorySupport.java:896)
        at org.codehaus.gmaven.runtime.support.stubgen.model.ModelFactorySupport.importDef(ModelFactorySupport.java:185)
        at org.codehaus.gmaven.runtime.support.stubgen.model.ModelFactorySupport.process(ModelFactorySupport.java:122)
        at org.codehaus.gmaven.runtime.support.stubgen.model.ModelFactorySupport.create(ModelFactorySupport.java:90)
        at org.codehaus.gmaven.runtime.support.stubgen.model.ModelFactorySupport.create(ModelFactorySupport.java:61)
        at org.codehaus.gmaven.runtime.v1_6.StubCompilerFeature$StubCompilerImpl.render(StubCompilerFeature.java:101)
        at org.codehaus.gmaven.runtime.v1_6.StubCompilerFeature$StubCompilerImpl.compile(StubCompilerFeature.java:90)
        at org.codehaus.gmaven.plugin.stubgen.AbstractGenerateStubsMojo.compile(AbstractGenerateStubsMojo.java:160)
        at org.codehaus.gmaven.plugin.stubgen.AbstractGenerateStubsMojo.process(AbstractGenerateStubsMojo.java:131)
        at org.codehaus.gmaven.plugin.ComponentMojoSupport.doExecute(ComponentMojoSupport.java:60)
        at org.codehaus.gmaven.plugin.MojoSupport.execute(MojoSupport.java:69)
        ... 20 more
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I had the same problem. I was missing the providerSelection configuration setting for 1.7.

Try this configuration and it should work for you.

```
  <plugin>
      <groupId>org.codehaus.gmaven</groupId>
      <artifactId>gmaven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>1.2</version>
      <configuration> 
        <providerSelection>1.7</providerSelection> 
      </configuration> 
      <dependencies>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.gmaven.runtime</groupId>
            <artifactId>gmaven-runtime-1.7</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
            <exclusions>
              <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
                <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
              </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
          </dependency>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
            <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.0</version>
          </dependency>
      </dependencies>
      <executions>
          <execution>
              <goals>
                  <goal>generateStubs</goal>
                  <goal>compile</goal>
                  <goal>generateTestStubs</goal>
                  <goal>testCompile</goal>
              </goals>
          </execution>
      </executions>
  </plugin>
```

Comment: As Joshua mentioned below: At least source level 1.4 is required for Groovy to work as well (the Maven default is set to 1.3).

Answer (score 6):

That works for me as well with one small addition:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.5</source>
                <target>1.5</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Maybe there is a way to make this the default?

Comment: That's because the Maven default source setting is 1.3, whereas Groovy requires at least 1.4. So yes, you're right, this does need to be included in your pom aswell. (I already had this set in my super pom (as will most developers), so it wasn't included here)

Comment: Okay.  I haven't made a custom super-pom yet, although I've read a few articles about how that is done.

Answer (score 0):

```
<plugins>
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                    <compilerId>groovy-eclipse-compiler</compilerId>                    
                </configuration>
<dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
        <artifactId>groovy-eclipse-compiler</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.0-01</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
        <artifactId>groovy-eclipse-batch</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.5-03</version>
      </dependency>
</dependencies>             
            </plugin>   </plugins>
```

See this article, it helped me to compile both java and groovy

[Groovy Java compile together](http://www.s0hel.com/blog/523/compile-groovy-files-with-maven-in-your-java-project/)