# A required class was missing while executing org.codehaus.gmaven:gmaven-plugin:1.3:testCompile: groovy/lang/Closure

Tags: maven, groovy, gmaven-plugin, gmaven

I'm trying to `mvn clean install` a maven project that has landed on my plate, however I'm getting an exception which I believe may be due to a version conflict of Groovy, this is what I get :

```
Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.gmaven:gmaven-plugin:1.3:testCompile (default) on project maven-myproject-plugin: Execution default of goal org.codehaus.gmaven:gmaven-plugin:1.3:testCompile failed: A required class was missing while executing org.codehaus.gmaven:gmaven-plugin:1.3:testCompile: groovy/lang/Closure
```

Trace with the `-e` flag :

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: groovy/lang/Closure
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2427)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1791)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v5.Java5.configureClassNode(Java5.java:318)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassNode.lazyClassInit(ClassNode.java:263)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassNode.getUnresolvedSuperClass(ClassNode.java:957)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassNode.getUnresolvedSuperClass(ClassNode.java:952)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ResolveVisitor.checkCyclicInheritence(ResolveVisitor.java:1309)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ResolveVisitor.visitClass(ResolveVisitor.java:1286)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ResolveVisitor.startResolving(ResolveVisitor.java:148)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit$6.call(CompilationUnit.java:574)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.applyToSourceUnits(CompilationUnit.java:814)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.doPhaseOperation(CompilationUnit.java:511)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.processPhaseOperations(CompilationUnit.java:487)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.java:464)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.java:448)
    at org.codehaus.gmaven.runtime.v1_7.ClassCompilerFeature$ClassCompilerImpl.compile(ClassCompilerFeature.java:148)
    at org.codehaus.gmaven.plugin.compile.AbstractCompileMojo.compile(AbstractCompileMojo.java:200)
    at org.codehaus.gmaven.plugin.compile.AbstractCompileMojo.process(AbstractCompileMojo.java:164)
    at org.codehaus.gmaven.plugin.ComponentMojoSupport.doExecute(ComponentMojoSupport.java:60)
    at org.codehaus.gmaven.plugin.compile.TestCompileMojo.doExecute(TestCompileMojo.java:90)
    at org.codehaus.gmaven.plugin.MojoSupport.execute(MojoSupport.java:69)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
    ... 20 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: groovy.lang.Closure
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.loadClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:696)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.loadClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:793)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    ... 43 more
```

These are the relevant plugins I'm using :

org.apache.maven.plugins
                maven-compiler-plugin
                ${maven-compiler-plugin.version}
                
                    1.6
                    1.6
                    true

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.gmaven</groupId>
            <artifactId>gmaven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <providerSelection>1.7</providerSelection>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                        <goal>testCompile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.gmaven.runtime</groupId>
                    <artifactId>gmaven-runtime-1.7</artifactId>
                    <version>1.3</version>
                    <exclusions>
                        <exclusion>
                            <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
                            <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
                        </exclusion>
                    </exclusions>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
                    <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
                    <version>1.7.5</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
```

I've tried updating the versions of `groovy-all` and the `gmaven-plugin` , and I've also tried setting the providerSelection as suggested in a [previous SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2199547/maven-compile-mixed-java-groovy-1-7-project-using-gmaven-plugin)

This is my Java/Maven version :

```
mvn -version
Apache Maven 3.0.4 (r1232337; 2012-01-17 08:44:56+0000)
Maven home: /Users/JElsey/Development/tools/apache-maven-3.0.4
Java version: 1.6.0_32, vendor: Apple Inc.
Java home: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0_32-b05-420.jdk/Contents/Home
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: MacRoman
OS name: "mac os x", version: "10.7.4", arch: "x86_64", family: "mac"
```

Any pointers on what could be causing this?

**EDIT 1:**

I've tried downgrading maven to 2.2.1, and have repointed the symbolic link to ensure it doesn't attempt to use the pre-packaged 3.0.4 that Apple like to ship with as explained [here](http://cyntech.wordpress.com/2011/03/09/maven-2-error/).

I still can't get past this, I have no idea...

```
[FATAL ERROR] Container realm = plexus.core
urls[0] = file:/Users/JElsey/Development/tools/apache-maven-2.2.1/lib/maven-2.2.1-uber.jar
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] FATAL ERROR
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] groovy/lang/Closure
groovy.lang.Closure
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Trace
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: groovy/lang/Closure
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2427)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1791)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v5.Java5.configureClassNode(Java5.java:318)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassNode.lazyClassInit(ClassNode.java:263)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassNode.getUnresolvedSuperClass(ClassNode.java:957)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassNode.getUnresolvedSuperClass(ClassNode.java:952)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ResolveVisitor.checkCyclicInheritence(ResolveVisitor.java:1309)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ResolveVisitor.visitClass(ResolveVisitor.java:1286)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ResolveVisitor.startResolving(ResolveVisitor.java:148)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit$6.call(CompilationUnit.java:574)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.applyToSourceUnits(CompilationUnit.java:814)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.doPhaseOperation(CompilationUnit.java:511)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.processPhaseOperations(CompilationUnit.java:487)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.java:464)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.java:448)
    at org.codehaus.gmaven.runtime.v1_7.ClassCompilerFeature$ClassCompilerImpl.compile(ClassCompilerFeature.java:148)
    at org.codehaus.gmaven.plugin.compile.AbstractCompileMojo.compile(AbstractCompileMojo.java:200)
    at org.codehaus.gmaven.plugin.compile.AbstractCompileMojo.process(AbstractCompileMojo.java:164)
    at org.codehaus.gmaven.plugin.ComponentMojoSupport.doExecute(ComponentMojoSupport.java:60)
    at org.codehaus.gmaven.plugin.compile.TestCompileMojo.doExecute(TestCompileMojo.java:90)
    at org.codehaus.gmaven.plugin.MojoSupport.execute(MojoSupport.java:69)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultPluginManager.java:490)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoals(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:694)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoalWithLifecycle(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:556)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoal(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:535)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoalAndHandleFailures(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:387)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeTaskSegments(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:348)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.execute(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:180)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:328)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:138)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:362)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.compat.CompatibleMain.main(CompatibleMain.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:315)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:255)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:430)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:375)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: groovy.lang.Closure
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.loadClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:696)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.loadClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:793)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    ... 41 more
```

Answer (score 3):

I haven't seen the exact error you have, but I've found Groovy 1.8.7, gmaven-plugin 1.4, and gmaven-runtime-1.8 to be a successful combination. Note that I had to include jansi as a workaround for [this bug](https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GMAVEN-103) in `mvn groovy:shell`.

Add Groovy 1.8.7 to your dependencies:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
    <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
    <version>1.8.7</version>
</dependency>
```

Then add the plugin configuration:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.gmaven</groupId>
            <artifactId>gmaven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>generateStubs</goal>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                        <goal>generateTestStubs</goal>
                        <goal>testCompile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <providerSelection>1.8</providerSelection>
            </configuration>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                  <groupId>org.codehaus.gmaven.runtime</groupId>
                  <artifactId>gmaven-runtime-1.8</artifactId>
                  <version>1.4</version>
                  <exclusions>
                    <exclusion>
                      <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
                      <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                  </exclusions>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                  <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
                  <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
                  <version>1.8.7</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.fusesource.jansi</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jansi</artifactId>
                    <version>1.9</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 0):

Also try this one for newer versions of Groovy and others:

---

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
   <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
   <version>2.4.1</version>
</dependency>
```

---

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.gmaven</groupId>
    <artifactId>gmaven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.5</version>
    <executions>
       <execution>
          <goals>
              <goal>generateStubs</goal>
              <goal>compile</goal>
              <goal>generateTestStubs</goal>
              <goal>testCompile</goal>
          </goals>
       </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <providerSelection>1.8</providerSelection>
        <source/>
    </configuration>
    <dependencies>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.codehaus.gmaven.runtime</groupId>
           <artifactId>gmaven-runtime-1.8</artifactId>
           <version>1.5</version>
           <exclusions>
               <exclusion>
                   <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
                   <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
               </exclusion>
           </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
           <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
           <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
           <version>2.4.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
           <groupId>org.fusesource.jansi</groupId>
           <artifactId>jansi</artifactId>
           <version>1.11</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

Comment: GMaven shouldn't be used to compile Groovy versions newer than 2.0.x.  The last time I updated GMaven was to compile the 2.0 provider against 2.0.1.  There are features that don't work at all with GMaven (like traits).  I shamelessly recommend [GMavenPlus](https://github.com/groovy/GMavenPlus), but you could also consider [Groovy-Eclipse](http://groovy-lang.org/groovyc.html#section-groovyeclipse).