# Techniques to add a REPL to a Java project

Tags: java, scala, groovy, clojure, read-eval-print-loop

What techniques that people have found useful using Clojure, Scala, JRuby, build tools, etc. to retrofit a Java project with a REPL to quickly experiment?

I often need to work with plain old Java projects (POJO projects?) and miss having a REPL. [Other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/397488/is-there-something-like-pythons-interactive-repl-mode-but-for-java) [SO questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2636044/java-repl-shell) address this topic, but these are several years old and the responses are dated.

I'll start by contributing a few techniques that I've used to solve this problem.

Comment: I have a script in `~/bin/` that contains just `scala -cp target/classes:\`mvn dependency:build-classpath | grep "^[^\[]"\`` for use with Scala-pluginless Maven projects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the project uses Maven, the gmaven plugin and accompanying `mvn groovy:shell` is helpful, although getting it [configured](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2199547/maven-compile-mixed-java-groovy-1-7-project-using-gmaven-plugin) [correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11827190/a-required-class-was-missing-while-executing-org-codehaus-gmavengmaven-plugin1) can be challenging.

For those projects not using Maven, a common pattern is to include dependencies in a lib folder and manage them manually. For these, I've used groovy:

```
groovysh -cp `echo lib/*.jar | sed 's/ /:/g'`
```

...or clojure:

```
java -cp /usr/local/Cellar/clojure/1.3.0/clojure-1.3.0.jar:`echo lib/*.jar | sed 's/ /:/g'` clojure.main
```

The default Clojure wrapper can also be [enhanced with rlwrap](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Clojure_Programming/Getting_Started#Enhancing_Clojure_REPL_with_rlwrap).

Answer (score 1):

This question is primarily about build systems and the potential complexity of persuading an existing build system to incorporate a REPL. One of the things that I love about both [sbt](http://www.scala-sbt.org) and [Leiningen](http://leiningen.org) is that they both provide REPL support out of the box. Unfortunately moving an existing project from Ant/Maven/whatever to one of these might not be straightforward.

But if your existing project already publishes to a Maven or Ivy repository (or could be persuaded to do so easily enough) then you can create a new sbt or Leiningen project, import the artefacts published by your existing project, and you're done...

Comment: I'm also looking for solutions that exist outside of a build tool. sbt, lein, and mvn all provide a REPL, but ant, gradle, and make do not.