# How do I set JDK version for gmaven plugin?

Tags: java, maven, groovy, gmaven-plugin, gmaven

Is it possible to force the gmaven plugin to use a different JDK than the one specified in JAVA_HOME? We need to build a specific project using Java 7, but most developers will have JAVA_HOME set to a Java 6 install as all our other projects are still on Java 6.

The error message we get is:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.gmaven:gmaven-plugin:1.4:generateStubs (default) on   project XYZ: Execution default of goal org.codehaus.gmaven:gmaven-plugin:1.4:generateStubs failed: An API incompatibility was encountered while executing org.codehaus.gmaven:gmaven-plugin:1.4:generateStubs: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: <snip> : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The [Maven Enforcer plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-enforcer-plugin/usage.html) is an easy way to require a specific JDK version.

Comment: Yes, it will fail the build if it detects 1.6 being used - but it won't help us to actually set the JDK to use for the build. Unless we miss something...

Answer (score 0):

you can specify JAVA_HOME for maven task in ide or bat/sh file for example
  [Intellige Idea](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F9HXd.png)

and no need to change system environment variables

Answer (score -1):

Example configuration from [maven-compiler-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/set-compiler-source-and-target.html)

```
<project>
  [...]
  <build>
    [...]
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.6</source>
          <target>1.6</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
    [...]
  </build>
  [...]
</project>
```

The maven by default uses Java 1.4, not the Java set in the JAVA_HOME variable.

Comment: Sure, but the Groovy plugin seems to ignore the maven compiler plugin settings (where we specify JDK 1.7) and happily use JDK 1.6 for stub generation

Comment: Check if you are missing providerSelection configuration, more info in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2199547/maven-compile-mixed-java-groovy-1-7-project-using-gmaven-plugin

Comment: We tried that as well - no luck. I assumed this only sets the version of Groovy to use, is that in some way tied to what JDK is used to compile the code?

Comment: Well, if it is still not working, I would say it is a bug in the gmaven-plugin or somewhere in your configuration. There is an alternative to gmaven, which is more actively developed http://groovy.codehaus.org/Groovy-Eclipse+compiler+plugin+for+Maven

Comment: Could very well be a bug - if we set JAVA_HOME to point to a JDK 7 installation it builds fine. So my guess it that the gmaven plugin just uses whatever it finds there.

Answer (score -1):

You can set an alternate jdk in the maven-complier-plugin configuration. See [here](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/compile-using-different-jdk.html)

Comment: See my comments in bbaja42's answer - the mvn compiler plugin config does not carry over to the gmaven plugin.